# How can I force Visual Studio 2010 to reload files and projects that have changed on disk?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I often use command line tools to do source control updates of files and projects that I have loaded into Visual Studio 2010.  With previous releases when I did this I could force Visual Studio to notice and load the changes by doing a Save All.  This doesn't seem to work in Visual Studio 2010.

I do have 'Detect when a file is changed outside the environment' checked in the Options window, but if I sit and wait it takes minutes or longer for the changes to be noticed.

How can I force 2010 to notice the changes in loaded source files and projects?

Comment: After upgrading to Windows 7 from Windows XP made Visual Studio notice externally changed files much more quickly.

Answer (score 18):

You can reforce reloading a project by unloading and loading the project.

Right-click the project and select *Unload Project*, then, when the project is unloaded right-click again and select *Reload Project*.

Note that this requires that all modified files in the project either be saved or the changes in the file be discarded.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like this could be the same problem that I experienced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146028/visual-studio-2010-refresh-not-working). VS 2010 doesn't seem to pick up on file changes made outside the IDE (like if you add a file to the file system, and then click refresh in Visual Studio you don't see the new file, I experienced this on C++ projects).

You can refer [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/571874/refresh-file-list-doesnt-work-for-c-console-app-when-file-is-added-to-file-system) for the MS case, they claim they have fixed the problem in "the next VS release", which I assume would mean the first service pack for VS 2010.

Comment: VS2010 on Win 10 does notice when the proj or source file has changed, but if you use a wildcard in your proj file, it won't know to look for new files that match that filter.

Comment: @Denise Skidmore - Yeah, when I wrote that answer 7.5 years ago, Win 10 didn't exist :).

Answer (score 3):

Win7 shouldn't be a pre-requisite, though its possible an earlier edition (pre-SP1) of Visual Studio didn't work it. Upgrade always works, for reference the track changes option also needs to be turned on.

[image: Track Changes Option]

Comment: Track-changes already set, I don't under stand the rest of what you say.