# VS Solution Explorer won't include files from Git pull

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

I have created an MVC App in VS and did a Push on github. Collegue pulled it and could open it in VS just fine. After that I created a new model class and also did a push and it was pulled by collegue succesfully in the model folder. But, when opening solution in VS the file was not in the model folder of solution explorer. Why, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I do:

1. see the commit log
2. restore desire version

   git reset HEAD some/path

   git checkout -- some/path

Att.

Comment: Git did insert class into folder, that works fine ,but VS doesnt include that file in his solution explorer even after I restart it.

Comment: check this:

http://rickrainey.com/2013/07/27/visual-studio-and-gitub-the-basics-of-working-with-existing-repositories-2/

And

https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-recover-a-file-I-deleted-in-my-local-repo-from-the-remote-repo-in-Git

Comment: I did not use VS Git manager...I used desktop git bash, is there any difference about that?

Comment: You can restore the file in the directory with git bash?

Comment: Yes but why do I need to restore it. On my computer the file exists inside Model folder. It is there. But when I open the solution in the Visual studio my Model folder inside the project is empty..

Comment: check:

https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/01/27/reloading-all-projects-with-vscommands/

http://www.howtosolutions.net/2013/02/solving-project-file-error-could-not-find-part-of-the-path-with-visual-studio/#.VpkrC3UrIeI

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679243/how-can-i-force-visual-studio-2010-to-reload-files-and-projects-that-have-change